# How to fade in multiple hidden divs when clicking the corresponding button using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

I have a series of web buttons that are generated by a PHP script. Whenever the user clicks one of these buttons I'd like the corresponding hidden  to fade in using jQuery.

This is my HTML code

> ```
> <div id="confirmation-apple" style="display:none;">
>     Do you really want to delete this apple?
> </div>
> <input type="button" id="confirmdelete-pear" value="Delete" />
> <div id="confirmation-pear" style="display:none;">
>     Do you really want to delete this pear?
> </div>
> ```

And this is my javscript code

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#confirmdelete-apple").click(function() {
            $("#confirmation-apple").fadeToggle();
        });
    });
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#confirmdelete-pear").click(function() {
            $("#confirmation-pear").fadeToggle();
        });
    });
```

They work perfectly as shown in the [Fiddle I created](http://jsfiddle.net/C58HN/2/), however since the buttons are generated automatically by a PHP script (i.e. I can have an undefined number of buttons) I'm looking for a way to automatize the javascript code so that each button id="confirmation-**aCertainString**" triggers the fade in of the corresponding div id= "confirmdelete-**aCertainString**".

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like this in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mido_rizk007/qjzEF/) first to select any id start with "confirmdelete-" then after add click event we can cut the required name from its id attribute like "apple" then add it to "confirmation-" to fade it :

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('[id^="confirmdelete-"]').click(function() {
            $('#confirmation-'+$(this).attr('id').replace('confirmdelete-','')).fadeToggle();
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could select the button with `input[type="button"]` or `input[value="Delete"]`(to be more specific). Or assign a class to the buttons for example `delete` and use `$('.delete')` For the click event.

Then use [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to get the corresponding div. So you don't even need the **aCertainString** part.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
        $('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
            $(this).next().fadeToggle();
        });
});
```

Have a look at [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C58HN/3/).

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I might have other buttons in that page that have different behaviors (i.e. no fade in). That's why I'd prefer to have IDs and not simply take all the type=button.

Comment: Added another out of the box alternative but other than that you could just assign a class to the buttons and use `$('.delete')`

Answer (score 0):

Use a FAKE class in your buttons,

```
<input id="btnDelete1" type="button" class="btnDelete" value="Delete">
```

Select the buttons by the fake class, then for each one of them set the click event and fade divs, but your div's id must be like this SomeName + ButtonId.

```
<input type="button" id="confirmdelete-pear" value="Delete" class="btnDelete"/>
<div id="confirmation-confirmdelete-pear" style="display:none;">
    Do you really want to delete this pear?
</div>
```

and the way to show the divs is something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btnDelete").each(function(){}).click(function(){
        $("#confirmation-" + this.id.toString()).fadeToggle();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it without any ids could be to use a container class such as `div.fruit-container`

html

```
<div class="fruit-container">
    <div>Do you really want to delete this apple?</div>
    <button>Delete</button>
</div>

<div class="fruit-container">
    <div>Do you really want to delete this orange?</div>
    <button>Delete</button>
</div>

<div class="fruit-container">
    <div>Do you really want to delete this pear?</div>
    <button>Delete</button>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$('div.fruit-container').find('button').on('click', function() {
   $(this).parent().find('div').fadeToggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gavinbruce/CWsu7/